# Tables and queries in a database are getting dropped without any warning?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using MS Access 2007.

I run a routine that automatically does the following to a set of queries
 a. deletes, b. compacts, c. appends

It does this to external MS Access databases - not linked.

On occasion, I receive an error 3078 when trying to run my routine.

I go to check the database to find that all of the tables and queries have been automatically deleted.  Does anyone have any idea what causes this?

For reference, the routine that Executes the queries is:

```
Public Function execQuery(qry As String, Optional enginePath As String, Optional queryParam As String) As Long

On Error GoTo err_handler
    'Purpose:   Create a log entry for the query being run.
    'Argument:  The query whose execution we are logging.
    'Return:    Primary key value of the log entry. Zero on error.
    'Usage:     For a form, set the On Open property to:    =LogDocOpen([Form])
    '           For a report, set the On Open property to:  =LogDocOpen([Report])
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngObjType As Long          'acForm or acReport
    Dim strQry As String            'Name of the query
    Dim startDateTime As Date
    Dim endDateTime As Date
    Dim recordsAffected As Long
    Dim user As String
    Dim compName As String
    Dim dbFullPath As String
    Dim strParam As String
    Dim Dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim QDF As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim objAcc As Access.Application

    If tableExists("TBL_LOG") Then
        Debug.Print "The Table exists"
    Else
        Debug.Print "The table does not exist"
        Debug.Print "Creating Log Table"
        createLogTable
    End If

    strQry = qry
    dbFullPath = enginePath
    strParam = queryParam
    Debug.Print strQry

    Set Dbs = OpenDatabase(dbFullPath, True) 

    Set QDF = Dbs.QueryDefs(strQry)
    If Len(strParam) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "query: " & strQry
        Debug.Print "Param: " & strParam
        QDF.Parameters("[" & "Param" & "]") = strParam
        startDateTime = Now()
        QDF.Execute dbFailOnError
        endDateTime = Now()
        recordsAffected = QDF.recordsAffected
    Else
        Debug.Print "No Param available"
        startDateTime = Now()
        QDF.Execute dbFailOnError
        endDateTime = Now()
        recordsAffected = QDF.recordsAffected
    End If

        user = NetworkUserName()
        compName = ComputerName()

    If dbLog Then

        Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset("TBL_LOG", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
        rs.AddNew
            rs!QueryName = strQry
            rs!RunDateTime = startDateTime
            rs!EndRunDateTime = endDateTime
            rs!ComputerName = compName
            rs!UserName = user
            rs!NumberRecordsAffected = recordsAffected

        rs.Update
        rs.Bookmark = rs.LastModified
        execQuery = rs!ID
        rs.Close
    End If
End sub
```

The routine that compacts:

```
Public Function RemoteCompact(SourcePath As String, BUPath As String)
Dim KillFile As String
Dim aFilename As Variant
Dim SourceFile As String
Dim BUFile As String

'These lines assign the variables full path and filenames

SourceFile = SourcePath
BUFile = BUPath
Debug.Print "SourceFile: " & SourceFile & " BUFile: " & BUFile

'Copies file to backup folder and renames it with the temp_ prefix.
Set aFilename = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
aFilename.CopyFile SourceFile, BUFile, True

'This section deletes the original file if it exists.

KillFile = SourceFile
'Check that file exists
If Len(Dir$(KillFile)) > 0 Then
    'First remove readonly attribute, if set
    SetAttr KillFile, vbNormal
    'Then delete the file
    fnWait (5)
    Kill KillFile
End If

'This section copies the temp_ file back to proper location, compacts it, and renames it back to the original filename.
DBEngine.CompactDatabase BUFile, SourceFile

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a compact, the Database Engine creates a new empty database and copies the objects over to it. If an error occurred during the compact operation, you might end up with an empty database. You're copying and then compacting back to the 'live' path.

It's more usual to compact to a temp file, and then replace the primary file with the temp file afterwards, assuming the compact is successful.